# Sending HUP to Nginx resulting in never-dying old master process

Tags: nginx, phusion-passenger

Sometimes when I try to do a graceful restart by sending HUP to Nginx, I end up with a master process that never dies, it sticks around forever, and eventually my app becomes unresponsive and I have to do a hard restart.

There are never redundant worker processes.

It doesn't always happen and I can't figure out how to reproduce reliably.

I am running Nginx with Phusion Passenger.

Comment: Such behaviour may be caused by third party module, for example passenger.